# ArcGIS Maps SDK - Click on symbol and show popup with text

Tags: kotlin, arcgis, arcgis-android-api

I created a symbol on a map.

```
val symbol = PictureMarkerSymbol.createWithImage(
   BitmapDrawable(resources, drawable?.toBitmap())
)
val pointGraphic = Graphic(point, symbol)
```

Now I want to click this symbol and this click shows a popup for this symbol displaying some text.
Does anybody know how to do this?